# Syntax error when using NEAR with maximum_distance value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, full-text-indexing

How do I modify this query to search for the keywords that are only two words apart?

```
select id, SubjectText from dbo.email  where contains
 ([ContentText],'execute NEAR class near program near code near SQL');
```

go

These are the results i am getting :

```
id  SubjectText
1   examples for you 
3   Oracle classes starting soon 
4   Toms Hardware nes letter 
5   Registration starts soon  
7   Dreamspark SQL order  ready  
8   SQL classes free online  
10  Visual Basic key  
20  SQL Help   
21  A Free SQL Server Monitoring Package  
22  A Monitoring Package
```

Tried :-

```
select id, SubjectText
from dbo.email
where contains (ContentText,
                'NEAR ((execute, class , program, SQL ,code),2,true)'
               );
```

but get error `Msg 7630, Level 15, State 2, Line 2 Syntax error near '(' in the full-text search condition 'NEAR ((execute, class , program, SQL ,code),2,true)';`

I have tried

select id, SubjectText from dbo.email where contains
([ContentText],'"( (execute near class, near program ,NEAR code,near SQL ))"',2,true);
go

and

select id, SubjectText from dbo.email where contains
([ContentText],'near( (execute , class, program code, SQL ))',2,true);
go

and

select id, SubjectText from dbo.email where contains
([ContentText],' (execute near class near program NEAR code near SQL )',2,true);
go

none of them work they all produce an error PLEASE HELP

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you have? As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787(v=sql.110).aspx) says, only SQL Server 2012 allows you to specify a maximum distance between search terms.

Comment: I was using 2008 I upgraded and my query works. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Glad I could help, I re-worded your title and added my comment as answer, it may make it easier for someone else to find this

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) says, only SQL Server 2012 allows you to specify a maximum distance between search terms, so you will get this error if you're using SQL Server 2008.